# Running an exe in azure at a regular interval

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have an app (.exe) that picks up a file and imports it into a database.  I have to move this set up into Azure.  I am familiar with Azure SQL and Azure File Storage.  What I am not familiar with is how I execute am app within Azure.

My app reads rows out of my Azure database to determine where the file is (in Azure File Storage) and then dumps the data into a specified table.  I'm unsure if this scenario is appropriate for Azure Scheduler or if I need an App Service to set up a WebJob.

Is there any possibility I can put my app in a directly in Azure File Storage and point a task to that location to execute it (then it might be easier to resolve the file locations of the files to be imported).

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good scenario for Azure Functions, if you want to just run some code on a schedule in Azure.

Functions are like Web Jobs (they share the same SDK in fact) so you can trigger on a schedule or from a storage queue, etc., but you don't need an app service to run your code in.  There are some great intro videos here [Azure Functions Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/functions/) , and [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs/) is a link to a comparison of the hosting options between web jobs, functions, flow and logic apps.

You can edit the function directly in the portal (paste/type your c# or node.js code straight in), or use source control to manage it.

If you really want to keep your app as an exe and run it like that, then you will need to use the [azure scheduler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/) to do this instead, which is a basic job runner.

Decisions, decisions...!

Comment: @Russell - Azure Scheduler really isn't a basic job runner.  It can't directly run an executable for example.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/scheduler-intro/ it seems that the only actions that are supported are:

HTTP, HTTPS,
a storage queue,
a service bus queue,
a service bus topic

so running a self contains .exe or script doesn't look to be possible.

Do you agree?